# how to hide and show custom view in android development?

Tags: java, android, android-view

I have two view class that only contains drawing. I want to change the view class from one class to another just by tap the 'door' (on specific coordinates).

Here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.example.insidehouse.InsideHouseView
        android:id="@+id/insideHouseView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <com.example.insidehouse.BedRoomView
        android:id="@+id/bedRoomView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a ViewSwitcher.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html

You can surround your two views with a viewswitcher and have Android smoothly switch between views. You can even use animations to give your user more eye candy

Answer (score 0):

You can hide a view by setting its visibility to VIEW.GONE.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `onClickListener` in the view and use `setVisibility` to show/hide the door/bedroom

to go in (onClickListener of the door):

```
insideHouseView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
bedRoomView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

to go out (onClickListener of the door of the bed?):

```
insideHouseView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
bedRoomView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

There are other views which allows you to switch between views, but i never tried it.. [`ViewFlipper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) maybe.